# Is it possible to apply a Validator for each FormControl in a FormArray in Ionic3?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a `FormGroup` assigned like this:

```
this.homeForm = new FormGroup({
bicos: new FormArray([],HomeInputValidator.isValid)
});
```

And the all the `FormControl` are added in the `FormArray` like this:

```
addForm(){
(<FormArray>this.homeForm.controls['bicos'])
.push(new FormControl(null));
}
```

As far as I can tell, the validator is answering for the entire `FormArray`, i.e. when one `FormControl` is not valid, it triggers for all the other `FormControl`. I want it to answer (e.g. `valid/touched`) for each one of the `FormControls` inside the `FormArray` **individually**, is that possible?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Yes, specify it when creating `new FormControl()`

Comment: Could you give me an example @HarryNinh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your new form control validators with

```
new FormControl(null,Validators.email)
```

and then you can access them with this approach

```
const formArray = this.tableForm.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
const controlList = formArray.controls as FormControl[];

    controlList.forEach( control=>{
      if(control.valid){

      }
    })
```

I hope this helps to you.